# Provide google docs functionality in web app with service account

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to use complete (edit, comment etc.) google docs UI in my web app but use a google service account. Here are the requirements:

1. when user click on a button in my web app, it creates a google doc using google API and my web app google service account.
2. web app then opens the created google doc embedded [google doc UI] in my web app. The doc should be editable.
3. I'm hoping by using service account, the end user does not have to have a google account.
4. I would also like to show a custom user name in embedded google doc UI  so that other users can see who is editing/viewing the document.

Any pointers ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @noogui : I don't have any code. This is more of an architectural question.